# jquery ajax to pass js variable into php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to get clients viewport size inside php code, via jquery ajax, but something is wrong:

index.php

```
<body>
<script>
var h = $(window).height() - 83;
alert (h); // works
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'pass.php',  // I also tried index.php directly
    data: {h : h}
});
</script>

<?php
include ("pass.php");
$h = $_POST['h'];
echo $h; // doesn't work
?>
```

There is no echo in index.php.

Comment: success:(function(data){alert(data);}) works. why you include "pass.php"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Index.php**

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var h = $(window).height() - 83;
    //alert (h); // works
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'pass.php',  // I also tried index.php directly
        data: {h : h},
        success:(function(data){
            alert(data);
        })
    });
});
</script>
```

**And pass.php**

```
$h = $_POST['h'];
echo $h;
```

it gives me the output. :)

Comment: Now alert is there, but there is no echo ?

Answer (score 2):

You are posting data to `pass.php`
**But including `pass.php` will not give you data sent to this file.**
You have to consider `pass.php` as being requested separately.
From this file do your echo and to get the output you can add to your `jQuery` code (after `.ajax()`) this:

```
.done(data) {alert(data);}
```

Answer (score 1):

it seems that you include pass.php but this is the url called, so your code have to be in pass.php
add it to see if your request is well sent

```
<script>
var h = $(window).height() - 83;
alert (h); // works
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: 'pass.php',  // I also tried index.php directly
data: {h : h},
success : function(data, status){
       console.log("success");
       console.log(data);
       console.log(status);
   },

   error : function(data, status, error){
       console.log("error");
       console.log(data);
   }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thomas, I placed `$h = $_POST['h'];` inside `pass.php` but there is no echo, again.

Comment: try to add it to your JS and see in the console if the request is well sent